# Scala runtime error: NoClassDefFound, even when library exists

Tags: java, scala, akka, noclassdeffounderror

I am running an app which requires codifying a PDF to a Base64 in Scala (AKKA). This error keeps showing up. The interesting thing is, I have already added the library in build.SBT, and it has downloaded. I already tried using the keyword "runtime" in the classpath, but the error keeps occurring. I'm suspecting a version issue at this point. The error happens at runtime, the app compiles with no problem.

ERROR:

```
[ERROR] 2019-01-30 12:09:44.480 [local-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] ActorSystemImpl Uncaught fatal error from thread [local-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down ActorSystem [local]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64
```

BUILD.SBT RELEVANT CODE:

```
 scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

 lazy val codecVersion = "1.10"

 lazy val firmaDependencies = pluginDependencies ++ Seq(
   "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % codecVersion)

 lazy val firma = project 
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= firmaDependencies)
  .dependsOn(plugin)
```

Comment: If you have project on github, it would be of much help if you shared the link

Comment: there could be number of reasons for this error, are you using sbt multiproject ???

Comment: I cannot share the gitHub link (private company policy). Yes, I am using multiproject. 
What other specific data could I give  for you to look at? I am sorry I cannot share the whole thing.

Comment: well, I am not asking you to share you project :) I have similar error when sbt.version was different across the projects. Actually had this error yesterday morning. I've manage to fix that issue by setting sbt.version to the same value.